# A one liner question for marriage to a beautiful girl

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

**Question**: One day I saw an extremely beautiful lady
on this island which consisted of only knights (that always are truthful) and knaves (that always lie) and was immediately smitten with her. I
longed to know whether or not she was married, but I
did not have the courage to ask her. The next day I came
across her brother Alfred and he made such an indirect statement from which I could immediately deduce that the girl is not married. What could be the statement?

I have modified this puzzle which was initially of a different form in the book *The Godelian puzzle book: Puzzles, Paradoxes and Proofs* in the chapter *Some Curious Adventures* (Problem 7). Its solution is a bit different than this version of question.
Here is my solution:

> Alfred must have said, "If she is married, I am a knave. "Suppose the girl is married. Then, if Alfred is a knight, the statement made by Alfred indicates that he is a knave(contradiction).  But if he is a knave, then he must be false which will indicate that if the girl is married, then he is a knight. But that means Alfred is a knight because the girl is married. Thus, the girl should  be unmarried and you can hit on her!

You can suggest your own solutions.

Comment: How is this a question, exactly?  What question are you trying to ask?

Comment: There are quite literally infinitely many possible solutions of statements that would work. I'm voting to close this as Speculative Answer/Insufficiently Defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution's logic is correct, but I would not call it an indirect statement. (It is  a (direct) conditional statement.)

> For this purpose, a 'standard' indirect statement would be, "If you ask me if my sister is married, I will say no."